# c# waiting for a javascript event to finish

Tags: javascript

what i like to do is this: in a button object in asp.net c# I want to read some hidden fields filled by javascript with client browsers data.
the function in js if fire when the client push the button but sometimes when in c# I'm reading the hidden fields the js hasn't finish yet so I get the hidden blank.
what I need to do is somehow start reading in c# when the js function is done.

thanks in advance, any idea would be helpfull

Comment: I don't understand your question properly? When "the client pushes the button" how are you sending this to the server where the C# is reading it? Ajax? Form post? Can you give us a simple sample of the JavaScript and the C#?

Answer (score 2):

Just prevent the button postback from occurring until the javascript is finished.

This is a simple separation of client-side vs. server-side processing.

Comment: the button has this propertys OnClientClick="show11();" runat="server" onclick="ImgBtnLogin_Click" what I want to do is execute the javascript function show11() that is supose to write the value I want to get in the hidden field and after that send all the form to the server and read that hidden field with the c# code of the function ImgBtnLogin_Click but what's happening sometimes is that the page is posted back before the function show11 is done so the hiddenfield goes in blank to the server

Answer (score 0):

Use a callback function from client to server, signaling the server, that the client is done updating. After that, the server can read the values.

Comment: If the client is done updating he could send the updated values instead of signaling no?. I didn't know asp was capable of reading stuff from clientside apart from something that was send by the client itself